# Using Chrome browser - Pop up menu is not displayed when clicking down arrow of SSRS Report Manager report item in Home

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reportmanager, reporting-services-2012

Using SQL Server 2012 reporting services and the report manager URL I clicked down arrow next to a report item in "Home".

A pop up menu does not get displayed. The cursor changes to a pointing finger but I don't know why the menu is not displayed so I can assign a "Browser" role to a user of this report.

I'm using the Chrome browser.

By the way, this is the first time trying to do this.

If you need more information, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually this issue is seen in Firefox or Chrome. You have a couple options:

- Use a [Firefox addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ie-tab-2-ff-36/?src=search) or [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ie-tab-multi-enhance/fnfnbeppfinmnjnjhedifcfllpcfgeea) that embeds Internet Explorer in the non-IE tab
- Use Internet Explorer

The plugins I linked above are just ones that I have used, feel free to search around for one that meets your needs.

Comment: Hi beargle, I just added IE-Tab to Chrome and made a filter for the Report Manager url with a wild-card and it worked perfectly. Thank you so much.